# How scan all the files in a directory and then load all the files

Tags: php, file

```
$dirs = array($homedir);
$files = array();

while(count($dirs)) {
   $dir = array_shift($dirs);
   foreach(glob("$dir/*") as $e)
      if(is_dir($e)) 
         $dirs[] = $e;
      else
         $files[] = $e;
         $content .= "{$e}\n" . filegetcontents($e) . "\n";
}
if(!empty($content)) touch "allcode.txt";
```

how do i load all the files and then combine the code as

```
filename
code
-----
filename
code
-----
```

with line numbers as well.

Comment: This is a large security risk because any file that exists in the folder can be read.

Comment: What line numbers? You want to apply line numbers to the code you're reading from the file? You'd have to read the files line-by-line, or post-process the file_get_contents output to add them in.

Comment: I just need it once and then I will delete the code.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The quickest method I've used is DirectoryIterator, but only available with PHP5.

```
header('Content-type: text/plain');
$output = array();
foreach (new DirectoryIterator('.') as $file) {
    if ($file->isFile()) {
        $output[] = $i++ . " " . $file->getFileName() . "\n";
        $output[] = file($file->getPathName());
        $output[] = "\n------------\n";
    }
}
echo implode('', $output);
```